# How do I know when a control outlet has been set up in MonoMac?

Tags: interface-builder, macos, monomac

Basically, in my application's initialization, I want to set the value of a control's property once it has been loaded. In MonoMac, it appears that when the `MainWindowController`'s `Initialize` method is called, the control outlets are not necessarily available (they are null).

I couldn't find any events such as `LoadComplete` that I could listen on and then do the required initialization on my control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `AwakeFromNib` method in your `MainWindowController` class. It is called once all the objects have been loaded and connected.

```
public override void AwakeFromNib ()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib ();

    // Do something here with the outlets
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I figured it was something straightforward but I had no idea what the actual function would be.